Search across all organisations of an enterprise GitHub account for a specific repository
I have read access to non-private repos across all organisations on my company's Enterprise GitHub account.
We have specific orgs relating codebases for individual functional 'pillars' of the company, with an org dedicated to the CD process.
The CD repos contain links to the specific artifacts to deploy, with names co-responding to the repo name (without the organisation containing that repo) and I need to see the codebase co-responding to the artifact.
So, I do not know what organisation a repository resides in, but know the repository name.
In the Github UI, how can I search across all organisations, restricted to ONLY orgs under my enterprise account, for the repository?
